# DrRacket/Scheme: Contract violation, number expected?

Tags: scheme, racket

So I have 3 functions defined in scheme, sumlist adds up all numbers in a list, and mean gives me the mean of the list. mean2 calls mean and does the same thing, but i get an error. It says the error is coming from sumlist function.

```
(define (sumlist lst)(if(null? lst)0 (+(car lst)(sumlist(cdr lst)))))
(define mean (lambda x(/(sumlist x)(length x))))
(define mean2 (lambda x(mean x)))
```

This is how i call the functions

```
(mean 1 2 3 4 5)
=>3               ;it works

(mean2 1 2 3 4 5)
+: contract violation
expected: number?
given: '(1 2 3 4 5)
argument position: 1st
other arguments...:
0
```

I'm still new too scheme just got introduced to it last week, but it is really frustrating..what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `(define (x . y) ...)` is the same as `(define x (lambda y ...))`, 
the following implementations of `identity` are the same

```
(define (fun arg1)
  arg1)

(define fun 
  (lambda (arg1)
     arg1)
```

While the following implementation of `list` are the same

```
(define (fun . args)
  args)

(define fun 
  (lambda args
     args)
```

So when you apply `(mean2 2 3 4 5)` `x` is the list `(2 3 4 5)`, and `(mean '(2 3 4 5))` also wraps all arguments into a list so the call to `sumlist` turns into `(sumlist '((2 3 4 5)))`. In sumlist you try to do `(+ '(2 3 4 5) 0)` which won't work since `+` expects numbers as arguments, not lists. To fix this you need to define `mean2` as one of:

```
;; Just make an alias to mean
(define mean2 mean)

;; wrap mean
(define (mean2 x) 
  (mean x))

;; use apply 
(define (mean2 . x)
   (apply mean x)) ; apply undoes list
```

I'd use the methods in the order of appearance. Sometimes using apply is the best but not if you can just alias or wrap.

Comment: @user2968401 People who can answer Scheme questions competently tend to love Scheme, so saying that you hate Scheme is unlikely to endear you to them. I know for a fact that when I avoid answering questions where the OP says they hate Scheme.

Comment: @user2968401 - That's a shame, because learning Scheme can be an enlightening experience. In part because Scheme is so much different, and in many ways more powerful, than traditional "C-style" languages. You will want to use a good editor that maches parenthesis (emacs, vim, maybe dr. racket?), and should also have an attitude of more than just "let me do the bare minimum to pass this course" - which you seem to have since you posted this :)

Comment: you guys, stop taking my comment so seriously.